# Get the newest record from MySQL from 2 tables more optimalized

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have some problems with query in SQL.
I have 2 tables.

```
people
    +----+--------+------+
    | id |  name  | val2 |
    +----+--------+------+
    |  1 | john   |   12 |
    |  2 | adam   |    5 |
    |  3 | alfred |    3 |
    +----+--------+------+

data
+----+----+----+-----+---------------------+
| id | v1 | v2 | v3  |        date         |
+----+----+----+-----+---------------------+
|  1 |  4 | 15 |  18 | 2020-10-16 11:15:53 |
|  1 |  2 | 12 |  17 | 2020-10-16 11:22:53 |
|  1 |  3 | 13 |  16 | 2020-10-16 11:32:53 |
|  2 |  1 | 16 |  15 | 2020-10-16 13:22:53 |
|  2 |  3 | 13 |  25 | 2020-10-16 13:42:53 |
|  2 |  4 | 12 |  35 | 2020-10-16 14:12:53 |
|  3 |  1 | 21 | 12  | 2020-10-16 14:12:53 |
|  3 |  2 | 28 | 42  | 2020-10-16 15:12:53 |
|  3 |  4 | 30 | 72  | 2020-10-16 16:12:53 |
+----+----+----+-----+---------------------+
```

I need to get in one table ID, NAME, v1,v2,v3,date for the new date to all object from first table
something like this:

```
RESULT
+----+--------+----+----+-----+---------------------+
| id |  name  | v1 | v2 | v3  |        date         |
+----+--------+----+----+-----+---------------------+
|  1 | john   |  3 | 13 |  16 | 2020-10-16 11:32:53 |
|  2 | adam   |  4 | 12 |  35 | 2020-10-16 14:12:53 |
|  3 | alfred |  4 | 30 | 72  | 2020-10-16 16:12:53 |
+----+--------+----+----+-----+---------------------+
```

I need the newest record from SECOND TABLE for all people from first table.
I try do it by this query:

```
SELECT people.id,
   people.name,
   data.v1,
   data.v2,
   data.v3,
   max(data.date)
FROM people
JOIN DATA ON people.id = data.id
GROUP BY people.id
```

I got the newest data but v1, v2, v3 is random from table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want entire rows from `data`, so aggregation is not an option here. In most databases, your query would fail, because the `select` and `group by` clause are not consistent... But MySQL, somehow unfortunaltely, gives you enough rope to developers to to hang themselves with. Your query runs (if sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled), but is actually equivalent to:

```
SELECT people.id, people.name, ANY_VALUE(data.v1), ANY_VALUE(data.v2), ANY_VALUE(data.v3), MAX(data.date)
FROM people
JOIN data on people.id = data.id
GROUP BY people.id
```

Now it is plain to see that the database gives you *any value* of `data` rows that match the join condition - which may, or may not belong to the row that has the latest date.

Instead of grouping, you actually need to filter. One option uses a subquery:

```
select p.id, p.name, d.v1, d.v2, d.v3, d.date
from people p
inner join data d on d.id = p.id
where d.date = (select max(d1.date) from data d1 where d1.id = d.id)
```

The upside of this approach is that it works in all versions of MySQL, including pre-8.0, where window functions are not available.

Comment: It's possible to get this Select more optimalized?

Answer (score 0):

One simple method uses window functions:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, d.v1, d.v2, d.v3, d.date)
FROM people p JOIN
     (SELECT d.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.id ORDER BY d.date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM data d
     ) d
     ON p.id = d.id AND d.seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  It seems strange that the join column in `data` would be `id`.  I would expect it to be called something like `people_id`.